# Facebook share are not taking content from open graph tags

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I tried to share this URL

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fcouponagar.in%2FStore.aspx%3FName%3D1Click1Call&imgurl=Hotels&sum=jjj5&title=4-7%25+Rewards+Cashback

its not taking the values of content attribute of open graph tags. I tried to debug the url

http%3A%2F%2Fcouponagar.in%2FStore.aspx%3FName%3D1Click1Call&imgurl=Hotels&sum=jjj5&title=4-7%25+Rewards+Cashback

and it gives me proper values but while sharing its fetching other images, title , description. Can anybody please tell me where I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey, I realize this is old, but I'm having the same issue. Did you figure out a way to resolve this?